# Determine if target cell is in table column, by column name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a procedure if the target cell is in specific columns.

I am using column numbers to determine this. If extra columns are added to the table the system falls over.

My code is below;

- the column names are a "Activity", "Resources" and "Stakeholders" (in the table"Schedule");
- the columns are 5, 7 and 17, in the line `If Target.Column = 5 Or Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 17 Then`

```vb
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal
    If Target.Column = 5 Or Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 17 Then
        If oldVal = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            If newVal = "" Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                lUsed = InStr(1, oldVal, newVal)
                If lUsed > 0 Then
                    If Right(oldVal, Len(newVal)) = newVal Then
                        Target.Value = Left(oldVal, Len(oldVal) - Len(newVal) - 2)
                    Else
                        Target.Value = Replace(oldVal, newVal & ", ", "")
                    End If
                Else
                    Target.Value = oldVal _
                      & ", " & newVal
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: The headers in the columns corresponding to columns5, 7 and 17, which are called “Resource” “Activity” and “Stakeholders”. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the properties of a table, thus.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Long

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    c = Target.Column - .ListColumns(1).Range.Column + 1
    If Intersect(Target, .DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If .HeaderRowRange(c).Value = "Resources" Or _
       .HeaderRowRange(c).Value = "Activity" Or _
       .HeaderRowRange(c).Value = "Stakeholders" Then
            MsgBox "Yes"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like what I’m after. Will try it out - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use named ranges to avoid error in case someone add columns to sheet.
 
For example column "5" is column "E". So in cell "E1" you create named range like "ActivityCol" and do the same for other columns (using differentr names of course) 
 
Then in your code you could do something like

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()  
    Dim ActivityColNo as Long, ResourcesColNo as Long, StakeholdersColNo as Long 
    ......
    With Thisworkbook.sheets("Your sheet name") 
        ActivityColNo  = .range("ActivityCol").Column
        ResourcesColNo  = .range("Some name").Column 
        StakeholdersColNo  = .range("Some other name").Column 
    End With
    ........
    If Target.Column = ActivityColNo Or Target.Column = ResourcesColNo Or _ 
        Target.Column = StakeholdersColNo Then
    .........

End Sub
```